# Clarity on IntentService

Tags: android, android-service, android-preferences, intentservice

I have this service which extends IntentService.

```
public class RefreshService extends IntentService {

static final String TAG = "RefreshService";

public RefreshService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreated");
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyed");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return  null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final String username = prefs.getString("username", "").trim();
    final String password = prefs.getString("password", "").trim();

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyeds");

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please update your username and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        return;
    }

   // here code for fetching data and inserting into db.

}
```

}

When the settings are missing, instead of a toast message being show, I get the following error.

```
 07-12 18:28:33.125    2961-2961/com.example.krishna.yamba I/menu_item_selected﹕ [0,Refresh]
07-12 18:28:33.143    2961-2961/com.example.krishna.yamba D/RefreshService﹕ onCreated
07-12 18:28:33.147    2961-3637/com.example.krishna.yamba D/RefreshService﹕ onDestroyeds
07-12 18:28:33.147    2961-3637/com.example.krishna.yamba D/RefreshService﹕ onDestroyeds
07-12 18:28:33.181    2961-2961/com.example.krishna.yamba D/RefreshService﹕ onDestroyed
07-12 18:28:33.197    2961-3637/com.example.krishna.yamba W/MessageQueue﹕ Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {38f6505f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {38f6505f} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
            at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
            at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
            at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
            at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
            at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.loadSystemProperties(ViewRootImpl.java:5413)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:378)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:253)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:414)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:322)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I'm assuming the following are true

1. The code in onHandleIntent method is run on different thread.
2. Therefore it is fine to do some intensive tasks here. (in this case I'm just fetching and updating db)

When the settings are correct everything works fine. Then putting a toast message compared to fetching and updating should not be a problem right?

How to put a toast message when the settings are blank?

Comment: When and how is this service used? Does it run only when started by the user inside of your app? Or can it be started arbitrarily in the background (e.g. by AlarmManager)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntentService` executes its **onHandleIntent** on a separate thread. On the other hand, `Toast` runs on main/UI thread. In order to show `Toast` in `IntentService`, you need to do something like this:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {           
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(RefreshService.this, "Toast msg here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> The code in onHandleIntent method is run on different thread.

Correct.

> Therefore it is fine to do some intensive tasks here. (in this case I'm just fetching and updating db)

Correct.

> Then putting a toast message compared to fetching and updating should not be a problem right?

No, because you cannot raise a `Toast` from a background thread. That, in effect, is what the error is telling you.

> How to put a toast message when the settings are blank?

The right answer is to not use a `Toast`. That is the second-worst solution for telling the user of an error condition (the worst being simply not trying to tell the user at all). There is no guarantee that the user will happen to be glancing at the screen at the point in time while the `Toast` is readable, and so the user can miss the message. Use a [crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) or something.

Regardless, you need to arrange to get the main application thread to update the UI somehow... if your UI happens to be in the foreground. The modern solutions for doing that usually involve some sort of event bus. There are three major event bus implementations at this time:

- `LocalBroadcastManager` ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager))
- greenrobot's EventBus ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot))
- Square's Otto ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto))

The sample apps that I link to all demonstrate the UI-or-`Notification` pattern, where we update the user interface if we happen to be in the foreground, or we raise a `Notification` to let the user know about the event if we do not have our UI in the foreground.

Comment: Vote for EventBus.  Since LBM is in the same process, serializing data objects is kind of pointless, and, assuming nothing's changed, Otto doesn't handle thread boundaries simply.  We're reviewing our background best practices currently, so I may need to take another look at Otto, but LBM is falling out of favor (with our group, anyway).  So far EventBus has been great, except for associating a specific request with a specific Fractivity instance.  But I digress.

Comment: really very neat and detailed answer. But to help me understand debugging. You said the logs are explaining stuff. But I cannot figure out here exactly. Please could you point to specific in the logs.

Comment: @Napster: "You said the logs are explaining stuff" -- no, I did not. The word "log" does not appear in my answer.

Comment: @KevinGalligan: "serializing data objects is kind of pointless" -- I don't think LBM goes through parceling. That being said, I'm a greenrobot EventBus fan too. "a specific Fractivity instance" -- is a Fractivity something that is performed by Sprint's Frobinson framily? :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare So is there no way to figure out what went wrong here unless u happened to know these kind of issues?

Comment: @Napster: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: @CommonsWare "I don't think LBM goes through parceling" from an optimization standpoint, that would make sense, but I rarely make things Parcelable anyway. Lots of code, error prone (forget to update as fields added, etc).  I generally just add fields to intents manually, but simple POJOs with EventBus are much simpler. Also, registering on type rather than a string is pretty nice. Fractivity is my lazy way of saying Fragment and/or Activity. I have never seen the Frobinson thing till just now. I am in some ways very out of the loop.

Comment: @Napster "So is there no way to figure out what went wrong here unless u happened to know these kind of issues?" I think I know what you're asking.  If the question is "do I need to know about threading, Looper, Handler, UI modifications to effectively code Android?" Yes. You will get hints sometimes. This particular exception happens a bit higher up the chain than the general "modify ui in the main thread" error, but if you're doing a lot of Android, when you see "Looper/Handler" in a stack trace from a UI operation, you should have a pretty good idea of what's wrong.